# Node.js Error: spawn process ffmpeg ChildProcessError

Tags: node.js, websocket, ffmpeg

I wanted to make a program like OBS simply.

My ideal code behavior is to create a child process in Node.js and execute FFMPEG commands to send a webcam stream to yourtube live RTMP server.  However, the actual behavior is caused by an error in the child-process-promise module used in node.js.

I've checked several questions, but I don't have enough experience to understand them, and I hope there's a clear solution.

I guess it was because I couldn't find the command address of FFMPEG in the Node environment. Or is calling from the socket environment a problem?

I checked that the FFMPEG command works in a Windows prompt environment.

※ Note: FFMPEG environment variables are registered.

Environment: `Window10`, `node.js`, `ffmpeg`

The code took advantage of a simple WebSocket example.

When I first investigated, I thought that the only way to do this was to use "fluent-effmpeg."

I tried "fluent-ffmpeg" but I couldn't get my laptop webcam up and running in Windows environments as a parameter for the "fluent-ffmppeg" command.

I've also thought about using WebRTC, but I think it's not for personal use because it's a P2P connection. (I also saw how to connect a peer connection to a WebRTC server like Janus, but I didn't have enough references to understand it.)

Below is the code of the problem.

```
const SocketIO = require("socket.io");
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
const spawn = require("child-process-promise").spawn;

module.exports = server => {
  const io = SocketIO(server, { path: "/socket.io" });

  io.on("connection", socket => {
    const req = socket.request;
    const ip = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
    console.log("새로운 클라이언트 접속!", ip, socket.id, req.ip);
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("클라이언트 접속해제", ip, socket.id);
      clearInterval(socket.interval);
    });
    socket.on("error", error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
    socket.on("reply", data => {
      console.log(data);
      ffmpeg_command();
    });
  });

  function ffmpeg_command() {
    let arg = [
      "-f",
      "lavfi",
      "-i",
      "anullsrc=r=16000:cl=mono",
      "-f",
      "dshow",
      "-ac",
      "2",
      "-i",
      "video='HP Truevision HD'",
      "-s",
      "1280x720",
      "-r",
      "10",
      "-vcodec",
      "libx264",
      "-pix_fmt",
      "yuv420p",
      "-preset",
      "ultrafast",
      "-r",
      "25",
      "-g",
      "20",
      "-b:v",
      "2500k",
      "-codec:a",
      "libmp3lame",
      "-ar",
      "44100",
      "-threads",
      "6",
      "-b:a",
      "11025",
      "-bufsize",
      "512k",
      "-f",
      "flv",
      "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/8dfu-69k0-dxyw-896q"
    ];
    spawn("ffmpeg", arg).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }
};
```

Here's the error: The expected result is that your webcam is working and YouTube live streaming is successful.

```
{ ChildProcessError: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=16000:cl=mono -f dshow -ac 2 -i video='HP Truevision HD' -s 1280x720 -r 10 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -r 25 -g 20 -b:v 2500k -codec:a libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -b:a 11025 -bufsize 512k -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/8dfu-69k0-dxyw-896q` failed with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tricky\Desktop\Work\ESC\ESC_temp\node_modules\child-process-promise\lib\index.js:132:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\Tricky\Desktop\Work\ESC\ESC_temp\node_modules\child-process-promise\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:381:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:606:12)
  name: 'ChildProcessError',
  code: 1,
  childProcess:
   ChildProcess {
     _events: { error: [Function], close: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _closesNeeded: 3,
     _closesGot: 3,
     connected: false,
     signalCode: null,
     exitCode: 1,
     killed: false,
     spawnfile: 'ffmpeg',
     _handle: null,
     spawnargs:
      [ 'ffmpeg',
        '-f',
        'lavfi',
        '-i',
        'anullsrc=r=16000:cl=mono',
        '-f',
        'dshow',
        '-ac',
        '2',
        '-i',
        'video=\'HP Truevision HD\'',
        '-s',
        '1280x720',
        '-r',
        '10',
        '-vcodec',
        'libx264',
        '-pix_fmt',
        'yuv420p',
        '-preset',
        'ultrafast',
        '-r',
        '25',
        '-g',
        '20',
        '-b:v',
        '2500k',
        '-codec:a',
        'libmp3lame',
        '-ar',
        '44100',
        '-threads',
        '6',
        '-b:a',
        '11025',
        '-bufsize',
        '512k',
        '-f',
        'flv',
        'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/8dfu-69k0-dxyw-896q' ],
     pid: 18928,
     stdin:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: false,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 132,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 },
     stdout:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: false,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        write: [Function: writeAfterFIN],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 133,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 },
     stderr:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [ReadableState],
        readable: false,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [WritableState],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        write: [Function: writeAfterFIN],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 134,
        [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
        [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
        [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 1615,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 },
     stdio: [ [Socket], [Socket], [Socket] ],
     emit: [Function] },
  stdout: undefined,
  stderr: undefined }
```